# Добавить проект в существующий репозиторий?

Tags: git

Есть репозиторий на gitHub в нем уже есть файлы. Как добавить еще один проект в этот же репозиторий в отдельную папку например. Я его уже закомитил но как добавить в существующий репозиторий не создавая новый не могу разобраться

Comment: Один проект - один репозиторий. 1. Используйте git submodules или 2. скопируйте этот проект в "родителя", и в родителе сделайте коммит а потом пуш.

Comment: Уточни пожалуйста, ты хочешь создать дополнительную папку через GitHub непосредственно, или же через Git консоль?

Answer (score 1):

- Клонируете себе этот репозиторий
- копируете папку с другим репозиторием в этот
- делаете git add -A
- git commit -a -m"message"
- git push